# CSS: Trying to make hover box move up

Tags: css, menu, hover

Hi I am tryng to add a red hover box for Menu. The problem is, the hover box shows below the menu line. I am trying to get the hover box to move a bit more up or higher. 
Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q16jo.jpg

CSS:

```
#menu ul a:hover{
     color:#ffffff;
     background-color: #F48A8A !important;
     border-color: #F48A8A!important;
     height:70px;
     padding-bottom:30px;
}
```

(I am learning CSS, so not a pro. PLs help! :)

Comment: can use give us jsfiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: what's your css without hovering that.

Comment: why are you using a height: 70px; for the hover? are you trying to make the hover link more long?

Comment: Show your code with jsfiddle so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

remove:

```
height:70px;
```

...and add:

```
display: block;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing both the height & padding-bottom

```css
#menu ul a:hover{
     color:#ffffff;
     background-color: #F48A8A !important;
     border-color: #F48A8A!important;
     padding:5px /*to give some space around the text*/
}
```